# How to find the primary key in dbf file?

Tags: dbf

I've a Problem finding primary key in dbf file.

I'm using dbfviewer to view contents of the file but I'm unable to find out the primary key

many of the records are unreadable or may be encrypted.

e.g _2WI0ZEK7K , _2WI10EHT5 , _2WI0YA8HF & so on.

I'm working on project which connects my sqlserver database to the dbf file.

but for relationship in between I need a primary key.

Comment: Do you only have the .dbf file?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the DBF file is encrypted by checking the flag at offset `0x0F` (it should be `0x00` for not encrypted or `0x01` for encrypted)

DBF doesn't explicitly define a column as being a key (primary nor foreign) - the closest you can find is when the datatype flag reads `+` which means that column is auto numbered. I've not got any files to hand with that column type, but I seem to remember they are stored as a 4 byte little endian integer.

Comment: How To check the flag???

then on wat basis then I shud join the table 


I have the file Pls Give ur email address so dat I can send u the file.

Comment: Any hex editor should suffice to check for the encryption flag.